# Обновление данных во ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Пишу программу с тестированием, приходит массив текстовых данных данных,
в начале используем данные под индексом "0" и рисуем этот текст во viewController, 
при нажатии на кнопку "далее", данные должны смениться на информацию с индексом "1", вопрос заключается в том как это сделать, скажем с анимацией в право.

Comment: надо анимировать только label или переходить на новый viewController?

Comment: все делается в одном viewControllere

Comment: сделать контейнер с clipsToBounds, в него добавить label, когда надо сделать второй label справа в том же контейнере и анимировать налево оба label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, попробуйте так:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
            transition.duration = 0.9f;
            transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
            transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom

            label.text = @"new text";
            [label.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
```